# How do I clean out all data from membase database

Tags: membase

I have being looking through online documentation but cant seem to find any CLI command to remove all data from membase. I am running some performance tuning and need to clean out DB each time.

Thanks,

Comment: Membase has been [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/membase) for over a year now.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command to clear everything from database

echo 'flush_all' | netcat localhost 11211